# How to add an element if checkbox is checked and remove it if unchecked?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I have a checkbox as soon as my toggle is checked or unchecked the element will be added to the textarea.

So i want it to be deleted if it's unchecked, is there a way to do it ?

exemple.html

```
<ion-toggle class="toggle-small" toggle-class="toggle-calm" 
            (ionChange)="addElement()" >  Airplane Mode
</ion-toggle>
```

exemple.ts

```
 addElement() {
const messageTextarea = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('msg'));
const selecStart = messageTextarea.selectionStart;
const selectEnd = messageTextarea.selectionEnd;
let newMessage = '' + this.msg;
newMessage = newMessage.substring(selecStart, 0) + 
             newMessage.substring(selectEnd, newMessage.length)+this.element;}
```

Comment: Can you provide a working code snippet on jsFiddle or somewhere else? Then it is easier to help you.

Comment: I modified the core code, so you can see what the function do, i want it as soon as is unchecked i delete the element and if it's checked i add the element

Comment: @Taieb elemnt you mean (this.element)

Comment: @MuhammadAlbarmawi this.element is my username

Comment: @Taieb so if the toggle is selected this.element will be add to newMessage , have you check the answer ?

Comment: @MuhammadAlbarmawi it's only adding not deleting :'(

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-q6alsc?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just notice I declare a template variable ioToggle and use the checked property

```
    <ion-toggle class="toggle-small" toggle-class="toggle-calm 
               (ionChange)="addElement(ioToggle.checked)" #ioToggle >
    Airplane Mode
    </ion-toggle>
```

And you need to update the addElemnt function like this

```
 addElement(state) { 
        const messageTextarea = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('msg'));
        newMessage = this.msg +( state ? this.element : '');
        messageTextarea.value = newMessage
  }
```

Comment: It's adding but not deleting like i want

Comment: @Taieb I just update my answer and give an examble to prove the value is changeing , hope I just help

Comment: Don't know what's wrong but in my textarea if it's checked i can add and if it's unchcked it goes to the next char without deleting just moving to the next char

Comment: I got you point why it 's not working , is the textarey editable ,what I mean every one can enter text or you just display msg + elemnt ? @Taieb

Comment: I just update my amswer this how you must do it , otherwise you need deale with cherck and remove the element from the textarea or add it @Taieb